mw_ne10_fft_c2c_1d_float32_neon function call throws Memory fault (core dumped) error in QNX
mw_ne10_fft_c2c_1d_float32_neon function call provided by arm_neon is throwing Memory fault (core dumped) in QNX environment.
The linking of header file and compilation is successful.
Do I have to link the arm_neon library explicitly in the cmake?

Why did it core dump? What debug have you tried?
